# How to get media info when playing with VLC player

Tags: ios, ios8, vlc

I am using vlc player in my app and i want to get file information which is playing by using vlc, I have used vlc SDK. I have searched a lot but could not found any proper documentation for vlc player integration in iOS. I want get information as given below:

```
General
ID                                       : 2 (0x2)
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 915 MiB
Duration                                 : 8mn 31s
Start time                               : UTC 2009-06-09 14:15:57
End time                                 : UTC 2009-06-09 14:24:12
Overall bit rate                         : 15.0 Mbps

Video #1
ID                                       : 256 (0x100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 8mn 31s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Standard                                 : PAL
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : MBAFF
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Color primaries                          : BT.470-6 System B, BT.470-6 System G, BT.601-6 625, BT.1358 625, BT.1700 625 PAL, BT.1700 625 SECAM
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.470-6 System B, BT.470-6 System G
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.470-6 System B, BT.470-6 System G, BT.601-6 625, BT.1358 625, BT.1700 625 PAL, BT.1700 625 SECAM, IEC 61966-2-4 601
```

Is there any way to get this type of information?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Full-disclosure: I'm one of the VLC main developers and the current maintainer of the Mac and iOS SDKs.

The VLC SDK on iOS is called MobileVLCKit or simply VLCKit. We provide basic documentation on our [wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit). Additionally, I [blogged about metadata in VLCKit recently](http://feepk.net/2015/02/18/mobilevlckit-and-vlckit-part-2/), which should provide all the answers you need.

Note: your above output is taken from mediainfo, which is way more verbose. In VLCKit, you'll only get as much as information as you can get in the information panel known from our desktop variants.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i want to get candidate (bits/sec) of the video which is playing into vlc. I can play/pause video by using VLCKit but could not found media info.

Comment: Sorry, but did you read my blog post which includes the exact API call for this? :) Or do you want statistics about the data transmission?

Comment: I am so sorry, i think i missed something, you have provided api for fetch meta data. But i don't have any idea how to use this. I am using dropIn-Player example simply. vlcObject. tracksInformation doesn't allow me to get meta data. Please let me know what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: hello. i always got timeout exception when get thumbnails from rstp/rtmp link. can you help?

Comment: Please create a new post or ask on https://forum.videolan.org - please don't revive old posts with completely new questions.